# Replace consecutive duplicates in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, duplicates, numpy-ndarray

I have a two dimensional numpy array `x`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
    [1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4]
])
```

My goal is to replace all consecutive duplicate numbers with a specific value (lets take `-1`), but by leaving one occurrence unchanged.
I could do this as follows:

```
def replace_consecutive_duplicates(x):
    consec_dup = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=bool)
    consec_dup[:, 1:] = np.diff(x, axis=1) == 0
    x[consec_dup] = -1
    return x

# current output
replace_consecutive_duplicates(x)
# array([[ 1,  2,  8,  4,  5, -1, -1,  3],
#        [ 0,  2, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  4]])
```

However, in this case the one occurrence left unchanged is always the first.
My goal is to leave the middle occurrence unchanged.
So given the same x as input, the desired output of function `replace_consecutive_duplicates` is:

```
# desired output
replace_consecutive_duplicates(x)
# array([[ 1,  2,  8,  4, -1,  5, -1,  3],
#        [ 0, -1,  2, -1, -1,  1, -1,  4]])
```

Note that in case consecutive duplicate sequences with an even number of occurrences the middle left value should be unchanged. So the consecutive duplicate sequence `[2, 2, 2, 2]` in `x[1]` becomes `[-1, 2, -1, -1]`

Also note that I'm looking for a vectorized solution for 2D numpy arrays since performance is of absolute importance in my particular use case.

I've already tried looking at things like run length encoding and using `np.diff()`, but I didn't manage to solve this. Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you require the length of the number of consecutives values. This is not easy to get with numpy, but using `itertools.groupby` we can solve it using the following code.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
    [1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4]
])


def replace_row(arr: np.ndarray, new_val=-1):
    results = []
    for val, count in itertools.groupby(arr):
        k = len(list(count))
        results.extend([new_val] * ((k - 1) // 2))
        results.append(val)
        results.extend([new_val] * (k // 2))
    return np.fromiter(results, arr.dtype)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for idx, row in enumerate(x):
        x[idx, :] = replace_row(row)

    print(x)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2  8  4 -1  5 -1  3]
 [ 0 -1  2 -1 -1  1 -1  4]]
```

This isn't vectorized, but can be combined with multi threading since every row is handled one by one.